# XSL Choose Statement Does Not recognize XSL When statement

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML that has various conditions that should be evaluated to create a node.  I've researched multiple sites and my code appears to be correct but it always defaults to the "Otherwise" node.  One note:  I have no control over the XML that is being submitted and I'm having to build the XSLT based on only one value being sent over in the XML for each test. But based on the event name different people need to be referenced.  I think its my initial When statement because it never seems to pass that condition.  Perhaps the syntax is just wrong?
Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

```
<Event>
          <xsl:for-each select="hr:UserArea/hr:Id"> 
                <xsl:if test="@idOwner = 'Onboarding_Event' and hr:IdValue !=''">
                    <Name><xsl:value-of select="hr:IdValue"/></Name>
                </xsl:if>   
          </xsl:for-each>



        <xsl:for-each select="hr:UserArea/hr:Id">
```

```
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="hr:Onboarding_Event = 'US Onboarding'">

                  <xsl:if test="@idOwner = 'Managers_Email_ID' and hr:IdValue !=''"> 
                    <Person>
                      <Name>Manager</Name>
                      <Value><xsl:value-of select="hr:IdValue"/></Value>
                    </Person>
                  </xsl:if>

                   <xsl:if test="@idOwner = 'Onboarding_Co' and hr:IdValue !=''"> 
                    <Person>
                      <Name>Onboarding Coordinator</Name>
                      <Value><xsl:value-of select="hr:IdValue"/></Value>
                    </Person>
                    </xsl:if>

                  <xsl:if test="@idOwner = 'HR_Rep_email_ID' and hr:IdValue !=''">
                    <Person>
                      <Name>HR Representative</Name>
                      <Value><xsl:value-of select="hr:IdValue"/></Value>
                    </Person>
                  </xsl:if>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="hr:UserArea/hr:Onboarding_Event and hr:IdValue ='CES Onboarding'">

                  <xsl:if test="@idOwner = 'Managers_Email_ID' and hr:IdValue !=''"> 
                    <Person>
                      <Name>CES Manager</Name>
                      <Value><xsl:value-of select="hr:IdValue"/></Value>
                    </Person>
                  </xsl:if>

                   <xsl:if test="@idOwner = 'Onboarding_Co' and hr:IdValue !=''"> 
                    <Person>
                      <Name>CES Onboarding Coordinator</Name>
                      <Value><xsl:value-of select="hr:IdValue"/></Value>
                    </Person>
                    </xsl:if>

                  <xsl:if test="@idOwner = 'HR_Rep_email_ID' and hr:IdValue !=''">
                    <Person>
                      <Name>CES HR Representative</Name>
                      <Value><xsl:value-of select="hr:IdValue"/></Value>
                    </Person>
                  </xsl:if>
            </xsl:when> 
            <xsl:otherwise>                                         
                  <xsl:if test="@idOwner = 'Managers_Email_ID' and hr:IdValue !=''"> 
                    <Person>
                      <Name>EMEA Manager</Name>
                      <Value>Test</Value>
                    </Person>
                  </xsl:if>

                   <xsl:if test="@idOwner = 'Onboarding_Co' and hr:IdValue !=''"> 
                    <Person>
                      <Name>EMEA Onboarding Coordinator</Name>
                      <Value>Test</Value>
                    </Person>
                    </xsl:if>

                  <xsl:if test="@idOwner = 'HR_Rep_email_ID' and hr:IdValue !=''">
                    <Person>
                      <Name>EMEA HR Representative</Name>
                      <Value>Test</Value>
                    </Person>
                  </xsl:if>
            </xsl:otherwise>

        </xsl:choose>
</xsl:for-each>
</Event>
```

Here is a sample XML

```
<Candidate> 
            <UserArea> 
            <Id idOwner="Manager"> 
                    <IdValue>CES Manager</IdValue> 
            </Id> 
            <Id idOwner="Managers_Email_ID"> 
                    <IdValue>CES manager Email</IdValue> 
            </Id> 
            <Id idOwner="HR_Representative"> 
                    <IdValue>CES HR Rep</IdValue> 
            </Id> 
            <Id idOwner="Onboarding_Co"> 
                    <IdValue>CES Coordinator</IdValue> 
            </Id> 
      <Id idOwner="Onboarding_Event"> 
                    <IdValue>CES Onboarding</IdValue> 
            </Id> 
            <Id idOwner="HR_Rep_email_ID"> 
                    <IdValue>CES HR REP email address</IdValue> 
            </Id> 

    </UserArea> 
</Candidate>
```

Comment: I have updated my original post to include a sample XML and additional lines of the XSLT. Apologies this was not there to begin with.

Comment: so data is printing out, i tried recreating your code here but i'm getting parser errors.

Comment: Perhaps because I've only provided a subset of the full XSLT? I'm not getting any parser errors when I run it using the full XSLT and XML.  Only error I'm experiencing is that it always defaults to the <otherwise> node. not sure if I should post the whole xslt and xml or not because its quite lengthy. Thoughts/Suggestions?

Comment: I'm assuming the full XSLT is using namespacing ("hr:"). Have you tried  making sure your xpath selectors are correct? http://www.xpathtester.com/

Answer (score 0):

You are testing the value of an element named hr:Onboarding_Event but there is no such element in your source document.

Answer (score -1):

You need to make sure you are selecting a node to work against:

[XSL W3Schools Example](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog_choose)

Comment: Hi
I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I've given it the node to refer to in the XML and it appears to hit the Choose statement but it always defaults to the Otherwise line and seems to totally ignore the preceeding logic.